# I am getting error as per snapshot attached

Tags: python, neural-network

[This is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkMUr.png)

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns

import tensorflow as tf

data=pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/wine.csv")

data.head()

data.shape

col=['cultivars','Alcohol','Malic acid','Ash','Alcalinity of ash','Magnesium','Total phenols','Flavanoids','Nonflavanoid phenols','Proanthocyanins','Color intensity','Hue','OD280/OD315 of diluted wines','Proline']

col_name=data.columns

data2=pd.DataFrame(columns=col)

data2.columns

data2['cultivars']=data['1']

data2['Alcohol']=data['14.23']

data2['Malic acid']=data['1.71']

data2['Ash']=data['2.43']

data2['Alcalinity of ash']=data['15.6']

data2['Magnesium']=data['127']

data2['Total phenols']=data['2.8']

data2['Flavanoids']=data['3.06']

data2['Nonflavanoid phenols']=data['.28']

data2['Proanthocyanins']=data['2.29']

data2['Color intensity']=data['5.64']

data2['Hue']=data['1.04']

data2['OD280/OD315 of diluted wines']=data['3.92']

data2['Proline']=data['1065']
data2.head()

model=Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(30,activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax,name='hidden1',input_shape=(13,)))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,name='output'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01),loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,metrics=['acc'])

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

S_scalr=StandardScaler()

x=data2.drop('cultivars',axis=1)

x=S_scalar.fit_transform(x)

y=np.ravel(data2['cultivars'])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,train_size=70,random_state=50)

model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=20,validation_split=0.1)
```

I am working on UCI labroratory data of wine classification using deep neural network.While model .fit I am getting error. In data i have imported dataset from CSV file. Then I have changed columns names and store that dataset in another dataset that is data2. Then I have done further procesess.

Comment: I tried to edit your code, but there is much work to do to make it readable. Please edit the question with correctly formatted code.

Comment: the error is very clear what the problem is

Comment: Please do not send screenshots of code/error messages. Paste them into your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the last layer of your model `model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid', name='output'))`, you're putting the wrong output shape. You're supposed to put `1` as your data is not categorically encoded. Here's your corrected code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Load the data
data = pd.read_csv("wine/wine.csv")

# Define the column names
col = ['cultivars', 'Alcohol', 'Malic acid', 'Ash', 'Alcalinity of ash', 'Magnesium',
       'Total phenols', 'Flavanoids', 'Nonflavanoid phenols', 'Proanthocyanins',
       'Color intensity', 'Hue', 'OD280/OD315 of diluted wines', 'Proline']

data.columns = col

print(data.head())


# Define the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='relu', name='hidden1', input_shape=(13,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Standardize the features
x = data.drop('cultivars', axis=1)
scaler = StandardScaler()
x_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x)

y = data['cultivars']

# Split the data into train and test sets
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_scaled, y,
                                                    train_size=0.7, random_state=50)

print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_test.shape)

# Train the model
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20, validation_split=0.1)

# Evaluate the model on the test set
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print("Test accuracy:", test_accuracy)
```